# How do I send an array from my view to my controller in codeigniter using the anchor URL helper?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array that saves the values from a counter and I want to send that   array to my controller to open another view.

for example I'm in main_view.php in my views folder...
within my main_view.php I have a counter and a array that increase with data when something happens.

```
$counter = 0;
$arr = array();
foreach($value->result as $val){}
    if($val->somethinghappenedtrue){
        $counter++;
        $arr[] = array('data' => $thethingthathappened);
    }
}
$array_encoded = json_encode($arr);
```

then in my anchor I have:

```
anchor('controller/method/'.$array_encoded ,'Counter:: '.$counter, array('title'=>'ARRAY SENT'))
```

and in my view that I want to open with the anchor i have

```
controller{
    method($array_encoded){
        $array_decoded = json_decode($array_encoded);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array_decoded);
        echo '</pre>';
        $this->load->view('other_view');
    }
}
```

but it does not work
it gives me:

> Severity: NoticeMessage:  Undefined variable: $array_encoded

Comment: where did you get this error?in which php file?

Comment: can you show the URL? when you got that notice error

Comment: other_view.php is where the error happens and i also get `controller/method/[%7B` in the URL

Comment: show codes of  `other_view.php`

Comment: the other_view.php file is still empty. I'm trying to print the array out first and make sure that it is being passed before coding the view

Comment: @learningbyexample please show complete error with php file and code line .`Severity: NoticeMessage.... where ?which line?`

Comment: Didn't you tried with ci sessions

Comment: @FastSnail
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: WarningMessage: Missing argument 1 for Controller::method()Filename: controllers/controller.phpLine Number: 1740
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: NoticeMessage:  Undefined variable: array_encodedFilename: controllers/controller.phpLine Number: 1754

Comment: @Janaka I have not tried with sessions

Comment: So you can pass data from view to controller using sessions

Comment: try pass the data using query string. eg. `anchor('controller/method/?array_encode='.$array_encoded ,'Counter:: '.$counter, array('title'=>'ARRAY SENT'));` and change line `$array_decoded = json_decode($array_encoded);` to `$array_decoded = json_decode($this->input->get('array_encode'));`

Comment: @AirfulShishir just tried it and did not work. gives this error `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: NoticeMessage: Array to string conversionFilename: core/URI.phpLine Number: 510`

Comment: is this after click on the link? can you post what is the generated link from `('controller/method/?array_encode='.$array_encoded ,'Counter:: '.$counter, array('title'=>'ARRAY SENT'));` this code?

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen here http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html I think You will have to use
$this->uri->segment(3) to get the value of variable $array_encoded first and then you may now decode it and assign it $array_decoded...but then sending an array via the anchor url is probably not the best of things to do.I dont know the specifics of your codes but have you tried posting it via an hidden input field?